# Using picocli with picocli-shell-jline3 and configured java modules leads to unnamed module reads package compile error

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system, picocli, jline3

On a project with multi modules, we want to use picocli with jline to build a console app. For each module we created a module-info.java. But with picocli we are not able to compile our application. we have tons of errors like

```
module info.picocli.shell.jline3 reads package org.jline.console from both org.jline.console and org.jline
module info.picocli.shell.jline3 reads package org.jline.console.impl from both org.jline.console and org.jline
module info.picocli.shell.jline3 reads package org.jline.keymap from both org.jline.reader and org.jline
the unnamed module reads package org.jline.keymap from both org.jline.reader and org.jline
the unnamed module reads package org.jline.reader from both org.jline.reader and org.jline
...
```

we included following dependencies with gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:2.3.4'
    implementation 'info.picocli:picocli:4.6.1'
    implementation 'info.picocli:picocli-shell-jline3:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'info.picocli:picocli-codegen:4.6.1'
}
```

and our `java-modules.info` looks like

```
module foo.bar.app { 
    exports foo.bar.app;

    requires info.picocli;
    requires info.picocli.shell.jline3;
    requires org.jline;
    requires org.fusesource.jansi;
}
```

I followed the advice in FAQ https://github.com/remkop/picocli/wiki/Java-9-modules but it hasn't worked out.

If we disable java modules, the application can be built and runs as it should.

Does anybody had a similar issue and knows some advice?

Comment: since the modules `org.jline.console` and `org.jline.reader` are not really part of your module declaration, I am assuming they are present on the modulepath transitively... leaving two alternates - one, you ensure whether you need them or not, if not they should not be resolved transitively either on the modulepath(and should be on the classpath) OR two, you expect the library owners to maintain their modules to not export conflicting packages, meaning they rename the packages accordingly or extract out common piece of code into another module